# Not pulling to right repository?

Tags: github, repository, hosting, candy-machine

It's not pulling the right repository to move files I believe.
I am pretty sure I'm in the right directory.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svjFo.png]

It's 2:35 in the video I'm trying to follow along with - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_-mP0RjsVI&t=164s

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push, not pull.

You would need to create the target remote repository first (https://github.com/Deanyboybopper/Tester.git)

If you have not created it, install the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), and create it from your workstation with [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)

```
cd /path/to/local/Tester
gh repo create --source
```